# Rails 6 deployment interrupted for Compilation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
```

Running  the suggested command does not resolve the matter.  Then the `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` is blurted out over 60 times.  I am not even certain which is the hangup?

I even followed a suggestion using `npm --depth 20 update --save caniuse-lite browserslist` to no avail.

The oddity (and frustration with this webpacking) is that no new libraries were installed.

So how does one get the deployment compilation element running properly?